# button like facebook dosen't work with fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, fancybox

I've a photo gallery with fancybox, when fancybox is open outside the tittle appears a like button. The problem is that doesn't work.

here my JS:

```
 $(".fancyboxi").fancybox({
     padding: 0,
                openEffect  : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none',

                prevEffect : 'none',
                nextEffect : 'none',

                closeBtn  : true,
            helpers: {


                overlay: {

                       css: {'background-color': '#333'} 
                    },
                title : {
                    type: 'outside'
                }
            },

          beforeShow: function () {
            if (this.title) {
                var titulo=this.href;

                // Add tweet button
  this.title += '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none" data-url="http://kingpollo.it/'+ titulo + '">Tweet</a>';

            // Add FaceBook like button
                this.title += '<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://kingpollo.it/'+ titulo + '&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=500&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=23" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:110px; height:23px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';


            }
        },

        afterShow: function(){
             twttr.widgets.load();
        },
        nextEffect: 'fade',
        prevEffect: 'fade'

    }); // fancybox});
```

The twitter button works correctly. Why fb button no?

Comment: Can you provide the link with issue, or replicate issue on fiddle?

Comment: http://kingpollo.it/elaborati.php (the web is underconstruction :P)

Comment: I can see the FB button, what's the issue?

Comment: the problem is that i when clik on the button  in my facebook wall the photo was i cliked not appears

Comment: now when i clik get this error:
The content you're trying to share includes a link that's been blocked for being spammy or unsafe:Body of an error/warning message. Title is: You can't post this because it has a blocked link.For more information, visit the Help Center. If you think you're seeing this by mistake, please let us know.

Comment: have you checked http://jsfiddle.net/G5TC3/ ? ... is right from http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful No. 13

Comment: yes, I tried that, but for each of the gallery dosen't work , and an other hand ,if I put as the URL address of a page instead of a picture if it works... :S Why ?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Add FaceBook like button
this.title += '<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/
```

That part of the code is missing the correct fb url.

```
// Add FaceBook like button
this.title += '<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the full url for the facebook button:

```
<a title="1st title" class="fancybox" href="/images/pic1_full.jpg">
<img alt="Photo number 1" src="images/pic1.jpg"
```

doesn't work but:

```
<a title="1st title" class="fancybox" href="http://www.yousite.com/images/pic1_full.jpg">
<img alt="Photo number 1" src="images/pic1.jpg"
```

Works